# Uniform B-Spline using deBoor's algorithm issue

Tags: c#, recursion, bezier, curve, spline

I have a very simple case in which I need to draw a single uniform B-spline segment of degree 2 (4 control points) and I'm trying to implement deBoor's algorithm in C#(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Boor%27s_algorithm) but I'm running into an issue and no amount of reading and researching has helped me find out what is going on.

In my case I only have 4 control points (p1, p2, p3 and p4) defined in a Point[] array. So I only need the curve segment between points p2 and p3. Because of that, I have constructed a uniform knots array without leading and trailing knots [0, 1, 2, 3] - basically I can just use i in this case but I do it for the sake of sticking to the formula.
I built an implementation of the recursive formula from Wikipedia:

[image]
[image]

Which looks like this:

```
    Point deBoor(int i, int k, float t, int[] knots)
    {
        //i - knot span index
        //k - degree
        // t - time [0-knots.Length-1]
        //knots - the knots array
        if (k == 0) return points[knots[i]]/3f;
        return ((t - knots[i]) / (knots[i + k] - knots[i])) * deBoor(i, k - 1, t, knots) + ((knots[i + k + 1] - t) / (knots[i + k + 1] - knots[i + 1])) * deBoor(i + 1, k - 1, t, knots);
    }
```

I try to get the point form the deBoor method like this:

```
float t = time * (points.Length - 1); //time ranges from 0 to 1
int[] knots = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
point = deBoor(0, 2, t, knots);
```

Unfortunately, the result I get is not correct. This image shows what my control points look like, what I'm expecting to get and what I'm actually getting:
[image]

I looked at other implementations, like this one: https://gist.github.com/soraphis/61ee9185416ee23d0d40 and they all seem to do the same, just coded differently. I tried to copy their solutions but I got even worse results. All this makes me think that I'm missing something painfully obvious.

Comment: could you elaborate this into a minimal, complete example so we could debug? for example, definition and runtime values of `points`, and method/loop where the results from the call to deBoor are used.

Comment: @dlatikay Certainly. Here it is using the same control points from the image: [https://pastebin.com/mn8SDHbc](https://pastebin.com/mn8SDHbc)

Comment: The knot vector does not seem to be correct. For a degree 2 B-spline with 4 control points, the knot vector should have 7 knot values such as [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2]. Also, the phrase "the curve segment between p2 and p3" does not carry much meaning as p2 and p3 will not lie on the curve unless you are referring to the curve segment bound by the projected points from p2 and p3.

Comment: Thanks, @fang I had previously tried with this set of knots - 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2 but unfortunately this does not even produce a curve. It produces the position of the first control point along when I call deBoor(0, 2, t, knots) for any value of t (0 - (points.Length-1)). This is the reason I constructed the knots array I'm currently using. My understanding of the knots vector is that it provides a way to get the curve segments bound by any set of control points and in my case I only need the segment bound by p2 and p3 and will never need anything outside of that.

Comment: I wrote this up over on https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#bsplines a while back, might come in useful here?

Comment: @OP: The implementation of your deBoor() function is quite dubious as I can see that it returns "points[knots[i]]/3f" when k = 0. It is quite strange that you use knots[i] as index for the points[] array as knot value could be floating point values, not just integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be confusing knots and control points. There are several things that we need to improve in your solution in order to make it work.

### Degree zero functions

As already noted by @fang, your solution for `k==0` is strange. I suggest replacing

```
if (k == 0) return points[knots[i]]/3f;
```

by something closer to the original formula, such as

```
if (k==0)
{
  if (t <= knots[i] && t < knots[i+1])
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

### Knot vector

As also noted by @fang, for a quadratic spline with four control points you need seven knots. You mentioned that you want uniform knots and based on your expected picture I would recommend

```
int[] knots = new float[] {0, 1/6, 2/6, 3/6, 4/6, 5/6, 1};
```

Note that the knots are now between 0 and 1; this means that `t` and `time` will be the same, i.e.,

```
float t = time; //time ranges from 0 to 1 and so does t
```

If you insist on your knots being `int`s (which, IMHO, contributed to your confusion) use

```
int[] knots = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
float t = time * 6; //time ranges from 0 to 1 and t from 0 to 6
```

Note the swapped order: `t` has to be `time` scaled to cover the whole range of knots.

### Evaluation

De Boor's algorithm evaluates one *B-spline*, i.e., one of the basis functions (some people use a conflicting nomenclature and use the word B-spline for the whole spline function and not just one of the basis functions; this sometimes leads to confusion).

Informally speaking, for a given `t`, your `deBoor` function gives you the coefficient of the `i`-th control point, which is a *scalar*. Therefore, the return value of `deBoor` has to be a `float` or `double` or something similar and certainly not a `point`.

For each `t` you need to sum the control points scaled by these coefficients. So your final result will be something like

```
point value = deBoor(0, 2, t, knots) * points[0]
  + deBoor(1, 2, t, knots) * points[1]
  + deBoor(2, 2, t, knots) * points[2]
  + deBoor(3, 2, t, knots) * points[3];
```

Note that `*` denotes a multiplication of a `float` and a `point` (you might need to overload such an operator) and `+` denotes a sum of two `point`s (again, operator overloading might be required). I'm not very versed in C#, so there might be a more elegant way of writing it down; for instance, I invite you to use a `for` loop.

If you are still confused, I recommend first getting acquainted with Bézier curves and then proceed to B-splines. Relatively concise introduction can be found for instance [here](http://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/notes.html). The pictures are a bit 90s-style but the ideas are still valid and presented in an understandable and concise way.